# MVC Routing and Navigation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

My problem concerns web application navigation.
I am using the Areas folder.
After I load a page that lives in the Areas folder I can not navigate to pages that are in the View folder off the root.

Example:

Folder in in Areas Called Maintenance
View is called Bank
Bank Page loads fine using menu.

Now I want to load the About Page
About Page lives in View folder off Root.

When I click the About Menu Item the URL reads http:\mysite\maintenance\home\about.
The correct url is http:\mysite\home\about.

Note that before I load a page that lives in the Areas folder I can load the about page without an issue.

Gerry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correct, in your view when you're generating your links, you want to generate one from within an area back to the root of the site not in an area.

To do this you have to tell the routing engine that you want no area.

```
@Html.ActionLink("About Link Text", "About", "Home", new { area = "" }, null);
```

Passing an empty area should get you back to the top.

EDIT:

Created a test case to verify.

All works as expected.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this question.